# Making specific elements change position on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I was not able to write a satisfactory title, so it does not have to do anything with my topic. I want to know how to move links when I go over them, but without moving the other ones as well. I tried to put different classes, but I did not fix the problem.
Here there is an example. Briefly, when I go over the first twitter, I do not want that the second one moves.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTwtk/233/)

```
a#twitter{
    display:block;
    background:url(http://www.livefluid.com/img/twitter-sprite.png) no-repeat 0px 0px scroll;
    width:72px;
    height:28px;
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;  
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

a#twitter:hover{
    margin-top:20px;
    background-position:0px -28px;
}
```

Comment: You couldn't think of a good title so you wrote a completely unconnected one? I changed the title to something hopefully better. The original was "Constructing images using HTML markup?".

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/AeMpL/)

I've changed your links and CSS to use classes instead of ids.

## HTML

```
<a class="twitter" href='http://www.twitter.com'></a>
<a class="twitter" href='http://www.twitter.com'></a>
```

## CSS

```
a.twitter {
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(http://www.livefluid.com/img/twitter-sprite.png) no-repeat 0px 0px scroll;
    width:72px;
    height:28px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
a.twitter:hover {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-position:0px -28px;
}
```